# Can I create a closure in Ruby that adds functionality to a method and maintains its parameter definitions?

Tags: ruby, closures

I would like to make a method that can take in a method name or other callable block and return a proc/lambda in order to add additional functionality, such as a call counter.

Here I have an example of a closure that defines a lambda and maintains a counter. This is working as expected.

```
def get_countable_greeter
  method_use_count = 0
  lambda do |greeting: 'Hello', name: 'you'|
    puts "#{greeting}, #{name}!"
    method_use_count += 1
    puts "call count: #{method_use_count}"
  end
end

greeter = get_countable_greeter
greeter.call
greeter.call(greeting:'Hi', name: 'Mom')

# OUTPUT:
# Hello, you!
# call count: 1
# Hi, Mom!
# call count: 2
```

What I really want is a more generalized solution.  I'd like to be able to do something like the following, that would let me basically add on the concept of a counter to an already defined method:

```
def greet(greeting: 'Hello', name: 'you')
  puts "#{greeting}, #{name}!"
end

def get_countable_method(method_name)
  method_use_count = 0
  Proc.new do
    # What goes here?
    method_use_count += 1
    puts "call count: #{method_use_count}"
  end
end

greeter = get_countable_method(:greet)
greeter.call
greeter.call(greeting:'Hi', name: 'Mom')
```

I can't figure out any way to pass along the arguments properly.  Is this even possible?

One thing I considered was somehow using the Method#parameters information for the passed in method name, but that doesn't maintain the default values of the original method. Any assistance or alternative approaches would be very appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for [curry](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Proc.html#method-i-curry) ?

Comment: I think you are looking for [`Object#method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Object.html#method-i-method) and argument fowarding. Example:  https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/HonoredDeterminedFiles#main.rb

Comment: You possibly could, but I can't think of a valid reason to do this. In Ruby, methods are first class language features, but blocks, procs, and lambdas are more or less collaborators rather than first-class functions. You probably want a  factory pattern or memoization for real world use cases, not meta-programming via anonymous closures.

Comment: @engineersmnky That appears to do exactly what I want.  I got close to that solution when I was testing, but I must have been missing something. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Object.html#send-method) / [`public_send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Object.html#public_send-method) to dynamically invoke a method with a given name, e.g.:

```
def greet(greeting: 'Hello', name: 'you')
  puts "#{greeting}, #{name}!"
end

def get_countable_method(method_name)
  method_use_count = 0
  Proc.new do |**kwargs|
    send(method_name, **kwargs)
    method_use_count += 1
    puts "call count: #{method_use_count}"
  end
end

greeter = get_countable_method(:greet)
greeter.call
greeter.call(greeting:'Hi', name: 'Mom')
```

Output:

```
Hello, you!
call count: 1
Hi, Mom!
call count: 2
```

`**` is used to accept arbitrary [keyword arguments](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Keyword+Arguments) (and also to pass them along)

Comment: Thank you, this is pretty much what I needed.  Combining this with the answer from @engineersmnky that includes passing along all possible arguments with *args, **kwargs, &block provides a full generalized solution.